# Live jQuery events not firing for dynamic element

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

Why are none of the **live** (or dead) events I bind to a dynamic element firing?

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function () {

    var $filterBox = $("<input type='text'>").live("click", function () {
        alert("Clicked");
    });
    this.before($filterBox); // insert into DOM before current element
    return this; // keep chain
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I am calling myPlugin on several `<select>` elements. I thought it would work without the Live plugin if I bound it before adding the element to the DOM, but not even the live events are firing. Is it because my element has no ID?

---

**Edit:**
The following does not work either:

```
var $filterBox = $("<input type='text'>").bind("click", function () {
        alert("Clicked");
});
```

Comment: Not sure why i doesn't work. But live should only be called once for the needed selector. In your code click() should be enough.

Comment: RE: Your Edit.  That should work fine.  In fact it *does* work in my (and Nick's) jsfiddle.  So, do you have any errors on the page?  Can you open firebug?

Comment: How many elements are you calling the plugin on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by not using global variables that replaced each other, and iterating over each element in question with `this.each(...)`:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            // do stuff
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) works off a selector (since it checks the target against the selector at the time the event happens), you can't attach it directly to an element...you should just use [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) in these cases:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function () {

    var $filterBox = $("<input type='text'>").click(function () {
        alert("Clicked");
    });
    this.before($filterBox); // insert into DOM before current element
    return this; // keep chain
    };
})(jQuery);
```

[You can try it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/DnSgn/1/), or a bit shorter with [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/):

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.myPlugin = function () {    
    $("<input type='text'>").click(function () {
        alert("Clicked");
    }).insertBefore(this);
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/DnSgn/).

Comment: @FreshCode - sure it does, test it here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/DnSgn/ My guess is you have something *else* outside the plugin messing things up here.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect something else on the page is messing up my events, but I can't figure out what. There are no other live events affecting input or select elements.

Comment: @FreshCode - is another event handler returning false for example?

Comment: Aha! I was calling it on two selectors. Reducing to one (:first) works. Now I have to figure out why it only works on one - there is more code to it, obviously.

Comment: All right, in isolation my code works on one select list, but not two. http://jsfiddle.net/vgXPh/1/ Why?

Comment: Solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500298/my-jquery-plugin-events-not-firing-on-multiple-elements

Comment: @FreshCode - here's an updated/fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/vgXPh/6/ ...sorry busy with work atm :)

Comment: @Nick, thanks. I discovered the each(...) solution with another question :)

Answer (score 1):

The `live` method works with *selectors*, not detached elements.
You can handle the normal (non-`live`) `click` event, and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just bind it?  http://jsfiddle.net/9WvpA/

Answer (score 0):

Can it be just because `"<input type='text'>"` is not a valid HTML? You have not closed your tag. However, I am not sure whether jQuery is unable to close it for you.

Comment: Although, I loathe looking at invalid elements in my code, jQuery fixes it with no problem.