# My jQuery plugin events not firing on multiple elements

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I wrote a jQuery plugin to filter select list options. It works great on *one* list, but not on more elements: http://jsfiddle.net/vgXPh/4/

```
$("select.filter").listFilter(); // doesn't work

$("select.filter:first").listFilter(); // works
```

I don't see any global variables that could be messing it up. Am I calling my bind events correctly? JSLint doesn't complain. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably surround your code with `this.each()`, like this:

```
$.fn.listFilter = function() {
    this.each(function() {
        (...)
    });
    return this;
};
```

Comment: Hm. I'll try that. This is my first jQuery plugin.

Comment: It works! I'll have Jon Skeet bring you some coffee as a small token of my appreciation.

Comment: Inside the .each(...) I had to change to `selectList = $(this);` as `this` in the loop is not automatically the jQuery select element.

Comment: Don't you mean outside the .each()? In the loop it's probably the same as in the loop :)

Comment: `this` is already a jQuery object, it should be just `this.each()` :)

Comment: `this.each(...)` outside the loop is correct. But inside the loop `selectList = this` doesn't work.

Comment: @FreshCode - it needs to be `$(this)`, like my comment above says, `this` was originally a jQuery object..you'll need to wrap it now, see the fiddle in my comment on your original question:  http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/vgXPh/6/